# Blocking Queue with watermark

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I'm facing a producer/consumer problem, and I would like to optimize the solution I have.

The current solution is using a blocking queue that basically makes the producer wait when queue is full and wakes it up when there is space available on queue. For the consumer it will wait makes the consumer wait when empty and wakes it up when something new is added to the queue.

Another custom solution I have implemented is using watermarks, when producers threads are feeding the queue and it reaches the high watermark they are put state and they will resume only when the low watermark is reached.

**Is there something similar already implemented somewhere?**

Comment: So you want flow control for `BlockingQueues`?

Comment: What's the difference for you between blocking when the queue is full/empty vs.  blocking when the queue is almost full/almost empty? Sure it will allow you to do burst retrievals/inserts, but would that actually affect the performance of your code?

Comment: The idea is to reduce the polling to the producer data source, I would be able to execute less queries with bigger result sets.

Comment: Ah, so the producer is database driven, that makes sense. A message queue might have some functionality related to that, but if you have a custom solution already, I'm not sure if you want to add in a message queue just for this. I assume your custom implementation uses `remainingCapacity()` to control the traffic? How's it working for you, can you test the performance?

Comment: As far as I understand this is a latency issue? I mean that is what the watermark will do -  read ahead so that a consumer is never blocked or blocked for a shorter time? To reduce reads you could simply increase the queue and fetch size?

Comment: In fact I wanted with that approach perform optimized queries to database getting as much records as possible up to a certain limit and put on the queue, the connection in this case is expensive, so the less connections I do the better. At same time reader shall have constant work. My idea is to run queries with big result set when there is space enough on queue even before queue is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider the `LinkedTransferQueue` which make producer await for one of the consumers ready to receive? I think this will prevent the length of the queue from getting unexpectedly long...

Comment: Thanks for the hint will check it out, maybe a specialization of that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you really need another solution than a `BlockingQueue`, because you can also use it when you want to put elements into the queue in batches.

That's because you can querying your data source into an internal buffer, and then copy the buffer into the queue (which may block of course):

```
// Producer's main loop
List<E> buffer;
do {
    // initialize buffer
    buffer = new ArrayList<E>(batchSize);

    // read batchSize elements from data source into buffer
    read(buffer, batchSize);

    // put all elements into queue
    for (E element : buffer) {
        queue.put(element); // may block if queue full
    }
} while (buffer.size() == batchSize); // until less than batchSize read
queue.put(poisonPill); // some special element to communicate end-of-data
```

The same strategy can be used on the consumer side! Instead of taking a single element, you can first fill an internal buffer by taking `batchSize` elements from the queue (which again may block until enough data is available), and then process the internal buffer:

```
// Consumer's main loop
List<E> buffer;
do {
    // initialize buffer
    buffer = new ArrayList<E>(batchSize);

    int i = 0;
    E element;

    // take batchSize elements from queue; stop if poisonPill found
    while (i++ < batchSize && !(element = queue.take()).equals(poisonPill)) {
        buffer.add(element);
    }

    // process buffer
    process(buffer);

    // until less than batchSize read
} while (buffer.size() == batchSize);
```

Comment: nice idea with the buffer, but the queue is limited for a reason, with the buffer I would have other N element somewhere in the heap until queue can accept them

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need (in a different context). If your system does not require extreme performance you can just use `ArrayDeque` with synchronization.

```
import java.util.AbstractQueue;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public final class WatermarkQueue<E> extends AbstractQueue<E> {
    private final Queue<E> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();

    private final int lowerWatermark;
    private final int upperWatermark;

    private final Runnable onSuspend;
    private final Runnable onResume;

    private final AtomicBoolean producerSuspended = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public WatermarkQueue(int lowerWatermark, int upperWatermark, Runnable onSuspend, Runnable onResume) {
        this.lowerWatermark =lowerWatermark;
        this.upperWatermark = upperWatermark;
        this.onSuspend = onSuspend;
        this.onResume = onResume;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("not implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int size() {
        return queue.size();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean offer(E e) {
        final boolean wasEmpty = queue.isEmpty();
        queue.offer(e);

        if (queue.size() == upperWatermark) {
            if (!producerSuspended.getAndSet(true)) {
                onSuspend.run();
            }
        }

        if (wasEmpty) {
            queue.notify();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized E poll() {
        while (queue.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                queue.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return null;
            }
        }

        final E e = queue.poll();
        if (e != null) {
            if (queue.size() == lowerWatermark) {
                if (producerSuspended.getAndSet(false)) {
                    onResume.run();
                }
            }
        }

        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized E peek() {
        return queue.peek();
    }
}
```